# how do I write a algorithm to find genes in a large String

Tags: java, algorithm, dna-sequence

I'm writing a program to find genes in a large string of DNA.

My output is correct on small input strings of DNA, but when I test it on their example DNA string (which is very large—too large to check manually if my output is correct) it says that my output is incorrect.

Here's my code:

```java
public class part1 
{
    // find stop codon
    public int findStopCodon(String dna, int startIndex, String stopCodon)
    {
        int stopIndex = dna.indexOf(stopCodon, startIndex);
        if (stopIndex != -1)
        {
            if (dna.substring(startIndex, stopIndex + 3).length() % 3 == 0)
            {
                return stopIndex;
            }
        }
        return dna.length();
    }

    // find gene
    public String findGene(String dna, int startIndex)
    {
        if ( startIndex != -1)
        {
            int taaIndex = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, "TAA");
            int tgaIndex = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, "TGA");
            int tagIndex = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, "TAG");

            int temp = Math.min(taaIndex, tgaIndex);
            int minIndex = Math.min(temp, tagIndex);
            if (minIndex <= dna.length() - 3)
            {
                return dna.substring(startIndex, minIndex + 3);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    // put all genes into a storage resource
    public StorageResource allGenes(String dna)
    {
        StorageResource geneList = new StorageResource();
        int prevIndex = 0;
        while (prevIndex <= dna.length())
        {
            int startIndex = dna.indexOf("ATG", prevIndex);
            if (startIndex == -1)
            {
                return geneList;
            }
            String gene = findGene(dna, startIndex);
            if (gene.isEmpty() != true)
            {
                geneList.add(gene);
            }
            prevIndex = startIndex + gene.length() + 1;
        }
        return geneList;
    }
}
```

When executed on this data: [https://users.cs.duke.edu/~rodger/GRch38dnapart.fa](https://users.cs.duke.edu/%7Erodger/GRch38dnapart.fa)
This is my output:

```
this many genes: 106

number of length \> 60: 31

number of cgRatio \> 0.35: 54

longest: 282

CTG appears: 224 times
```

Comment: You might get more & better responses if you reframe the question for people who don't have a bio background. It would also help to give a small string and the correct output. I can say that "cat filename | grep -o CTG | wc -l" agrees with 224 appearances of CTG.

Comment: Welcome to SO, _isaiah paget_! Are you told what your output should be, or are you only told that your output is incorrect? My first thought is to check something easy, like the number of times 'CTG' appears. That can be a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> operation. ... While I was writing this, @Dave checked and found that you have that part correct.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to identify a *specific, concrete* problem with the execution of the code - this is not a debugging service.

Comment: By the way, you're creating a potentially very large String unnecessarily. Instead of `if (dna.substring(startIndex, stopIndex + 3).length() % 3 == 0)` you can do `if (stopIndex - startIndex) % 3 == 0)`.

Comment: @k314159 mmm that's a good point but this is a course exercise, I am not really concerned about memory

Comment: @KarlKnechtel your awesome dude

Answer (score 1):

The goal of findStopCodon is to find stop codon at a place that is a multiple of 3 compared to the startIndex. (Based on domain knowledge.)

If the stop codon isn't at multiple of 3 compared to start you should *continue* the search from that point, not returning the end of the string.

Comment: I appreciate that but the find stop codon function looks for the first occurrence of a substring, and then the next function ultimately takes the smallest, so by returning the length of the dna, its guaranteed that it wont be the smallest.

Comment: As far as I can see only if you have another type of stop-codon, but not if you have the same one again. So, CTAACCTGA will work, but CTAACCTAA will miss the second TAA.

Answer (score -1):

```
the problem with my code is that this function should have contained a loop, because in some cases where none of the nearest stop codons are multiples of 3 away from the start index, the function would return dna.length.
```

when it should have have continued looking past those nearest substrings.

```
// find stop codon
public int findStopCodon(String dna, int startIndex, String stopCodon)
{
    int stopIndex = dna.indexOf(stopCodon, startIndex);
    if (stopIndex != -1)
    {
        if (dna.substring(startIndex, stopIndex + 3).length() % 3 == 0)
        {
            return stopIndex;
        }
    }
    return dna.length();
}
```